# Mixing Named params with standard params Phalcon

Tags: url, phalcon, parameters

I have a url that loads fonts as such:

`/templatename/fonts/helvetica?weights=regular,bold,light`

in php it will dynamically generate a CSS file with the appropriate font referencing.

We just recently moved over to to Phalcon and it broke. I'm trying to figure out how to tell the router to use the the font name as a named param but also use the standard param style. with the question marks.

this is what my router looks like right now:

```
...
    "fonts"=>[
             "pattern" => "/fonts/{file:[\w\W]}",
             "route" => [
                 "controller" => "asset",
                 "action" => "fonts"
              ]
       ]
...
```

When I use the dispatcher loop, like this:

`$params = $this->dispatcher->getParams()`

The array does not show the weights param:

```
Array
(
    [template] => templatename
    [file] => helvetica
)
```

How can I get it to look like this without changing the URL structure?

```
Array
(
    [template] => templatename
    [file] => helvetica
    [weights] => regular,bold,light
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following URL:

```
/templatename/fonts/helvetica?weights=regular,bold,light
```

Then `weights=regular,bold,light` are the GET parameters.

You can request these inside Phalcon by using:

```
$weights = $this->request->getQuery('weights')
```

You do not have to declare this inside your routes, Phalcon automatically appends these `GET` parameters to the end of your routes.

Check the [Phalcon HTTP Request docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request.html) for more info

Comment: Look close Phill. This is actually an answer. You will have to mix up result from both methods to make your array look like you want.